# How to setup Google Webmaster Tools on multiple subdomains automatically?

Tags: google-search-console

Trying to add Google Webmaster Tools (GWT) to hundreds of thousands of subdomains making it impossible to add GWT to these sites manually. Possible to do it in bulk?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say that it is not possible to do bulk verification from Google Search Console. Each domain has to be manually verified.

But, what you can do to speed things up a little bit is to made a script to do one of the following:

- Upload to server via FTP the Google HTML verification file. This file is always the same file per search Console account.
- Rewrite by uploading via FTP the file that contains the head section of your website making sure the new file has the Google verification meta tag.

Another option would be to use domain registrars, this way you don’t have to do any of the above method, you simply add and verify.

Now, to add the domains to be verified open several search Console pages (browser tabs) and copy each domain, then get the verification method you have chosen to do its work by clicking the verify button, once you have all the verification files up.

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately the site has 800,000 subdomains x 20 languages. 
I am writing this because one had a malware warning and just by chance I had that on GWT. I am concerned more will show. What I am looking for our notifications when one of the subdomains has malware. But thanks for your help. I guess I should restructure the question.